# Splitting JSON-Formatted Single Column Into Rows and Columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, importdata, json

**PROBLEM**

Since Google Sheets doesn't natively support JSON data, which I'm importing, I'm trying to split the data into a matrix of four columns and an unfixed number of rows using only Google Sheets's native functions.

**DETAILS**

I've used the `IMPORTDATA` function nested in a `TRANSPOSE` function to import a JSON file [found here](https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers_exchange.json) into a single column starting in cell B4 as shown below.

[image: Imported JSON Data]

In cell D4 is this formula:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(transpose(split(regexreplace(query(array_constrain(if(mod(row(B$4:B), 14) = 4, "^", "|") & B$4:B,max(row(B$4:B) * (B$4:B <> "")),1),,9^99), "^\^",), "^", true, TRUE)))`

This results in an error:  "Text result of REGEXREPLACE is longer than the limit of 50000 characters."  Other attempts result in a single cell returned.

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to parse JSON data into a matrix utilizing Google Sheets native functions solely and without using scripts, such as IMPORTJson?

Comment: The short answer is YES, there is a way. Is this something you need to import once and then keep a static copy of it? Or is this something that needs to be updated periodically?

Comment: The URL the formula points to is updated regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the data before applying `regexextract()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    regexextract( 
      transpose( 
        split( 
          query( 
            transpose( importdata("https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers_exchange.json") ), 
            "", 9^9 
          ), 
          "] [", false, true 
        ) 
      ), 
      "(\d+) (.+?)[ /]([-A-Z]+) ?([\w]+?| )(?:]]})?$" 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

The formula will be do a lot of text processing. You would probably be better off by using [ImportJSON()](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON).

Comment: Brilliant.  Could you please explain, or point to where to find info for, the regular expression used `"(\d+) (.+?)[ /]([-A-Z]+) ?([\w]+?| )(?:]]})?$"`?

Comment: To learn the exact [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

Place your original `IMPORTDATA` formula in A1 of some sheet. Hide Col A if you like. Then in the top cell of some other column (say, Col B), you can place the following formula:

`=ArrayFormula({"Name","Ticker","Exchange","Data";REGEXREPLACE(QUERY({A5:A,{A6:A;""},{A7:A;"";""},{A8:A;"";"";""}},"Select Col2, Col3, Col4, Col1 SKIPPING 4"),"(data)|\[|\]|:|}","")})`

This will return the headers and all results; and it should produce those results quite quickly, despite the large number of data elements to be processed.

The four sub-arrays `{ __,{__},{__},{__} }` that form the QUERY have null pseudo-rows added to the end of each except the first (i.e. adding 0, 1, 2 and 3 null rows respectively), in order to keep the four array lengths parallel despite their having different starting points.